# Como subir um projeto Spring Boot em um servidor Glassfish ou Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, glassfish, spring-boot

Consigo executar a aplicação normalmente pela classe principal com o  'tomcat embedded' como dependência.
    Porém ao tentar executar a aplicação em algum servidor a própria IDE Eclipse informa que a aplicação não pode ser executada em um servidor.
    Reconheço a facilidade de usar o Spring Boot para desenvolvimento e testes, porém gostaria de subir a aplicação em um servidor já existente junto á outras aplicações que já estariam rodando neste servidor, sem a necessidade de outra máquina.
    Considerando este cenário, 
    Quais dependências devo adicionar ou remover no maven? 
    Devo remover a classe principal da aplicação( a que possui o método 'main' e 'SpringApplication.run') ?
    Quais configurações (em Java) devem ser acrescentadas, apenas as que forem essenciais para o projeto web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu pom.xml troque o empacotamento de jar para war.

```
    <groupId>br.com.teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>testex</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Coloque a dependência do tomcat como provided.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Feito isso gere o .war

> mvn clean package

Vai ser gerado um arquivo .war dentro da pasta target pronto para ser deployado no tomcat.